# Filter Mysql results based on condition

Tags: mysql

I have one table as follows

```
 id       | name  | action_date | user_id 
 1        | Jhon  | 2014-03-1   |  2
 2        | Smith | 2014-03-03  | 3
 2        | Jhon  | 2014-04-2   |  2
 3        | Jhon  | 2014-06-3  |  2
```

I want to select all users who did action say from March to April and stop doing any action after that ?!
in this case will be `Smith` With user_id `3`
I have tried nasted SQL but with no luck !

Also i have tried using mysql_row equivalent method like in SQL , please sea this

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @customer_no = user_id THEN 
                    CASE when
                    DATE(action_date) >'2009-07-23' 
                    AND DATE(action_date) <'2009-07-25'
                    THEN
                     @row_number + 1
                    ELSE 211 END
        ELSE 1
    END AS Customer_Number,
    @customer_no:=user_id as Customers_id,
    action_date
FROM
    orders
ORDER BY Customers_id;
```

any ideas to do this using only Mysql .

Comment: What have yu tried so far?

Comment: Is your `id` column not incrementing? it shows `1,2,2,3` instead of `1,2,3,4`

Comment: @EdwinKrause say it's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "NOT IN" ,
try this query to except some values from another table or same table

```
    SELECT table.`user_id` FROM table 
          WHERE (`action_date` between STR_TO_DATE('01-03-2014','%d-%m-%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('30-04-2014','%d-%m-%Y') ) 
        AND table.`user_id` NOT IN  
            (SELECT table.`user_id` FROM table 
                 WHERE `action_date` > STR_TO_DATE('30-04-2014','%d-%m-%Y'))
GROUP BY table.`user_id`
```

Or if you want to make it in one query:

```
SELECT min(action_date) as min_date, max(action_date) as max_date, user_id FROM orders_test 
where action_date > '2014-03-01'
group by user_id
having min_date >= '2014-03-01' and max_date <= '2014-04-30'
```

Comment: Second part of answer is OK

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY name
HAVING   SUM(action_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-04-30')
     AND MAX(action_date) <= '2014-04-30'
```

Comment: @SamyMassoud: Am I supposed to guess what error it gives you, or are you going to give me a clue?

Comment: clue is here `SUM(action_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-04-30')`

Comment: @SamyMassoud: But what is the "SQL error" that it "gives you"?  I don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(orders.action_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-04-30')' at line 1

Comment: This is wired it's now working without error and without any modification !!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tab.* FROM tab 
inner join 
( SELECT min(dt) as mindt, max(dt) as maxdt, user_id FROM tab 
group by user_id
having mindt >= '2014-03-01' and maxdt <= '2014-04-30' )  t
on
tab.user_id = t.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer , please check accepted answer as well

Answer (score 0):

select * from tb_name where action_date between STR_TO_DATE('01,03,2014','%d,%m,%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('30,03,2014','%d,%m,%Y') ;

```
I assume here that tb_name is the name of your table.

and you can read more on mysql dates

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach... That should do...

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (
 SELECT user_id, STR_TO_DATE(action_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as actionDate, RIGHT( GROUP_CONCAT( DATE( STR_TO_DATE(action_date,'%Y-%m-%d') ) 
  SEPARATOR  ',' ) , 10 ) AS last_action
  FROM  `table` 
 WHERE actionDate > '2014-03-01'
 GROUP BY user_id
)last_action_selection
WHERE last_action <  '2014-04-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM orders b                              # "b" for "between"
  LEFT JOIN orders a                       # "a" for "after"
      ON b.user_id = a.user_id
      AND '2014-05-01' <= a.action_date    # "a" is after May 1st, 2014
WHERE a.user_id IS NULL                    # there is no "after April 1st"
  AND b.action_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-04-30'
```

It joins the `orders` table as `b` ("b" for "between") against itself aliased as `a` ("a" for "after"). Each row from `b` is paired with all the rows from `a` having the same `user_id` (orders of the same user) that  have the `action_date` later than May 1st, 2014.

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the rows from `b` appear in the joined result set. When no matching row is found in `b`, a row full of `NULL` values is used instead.

The where condition `b.action_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-04-30'` keeps only the orders from `b` that happened in March and April 2014 and the condition `a.user_id IS NULL` filters out all the rows that have pairs in the join (i.e. the same user also had an order after May 1st).

The query returns a list of rows from table `order`. If you need only the field `user_id` then you need to add `DISTINCT` to get rid of the duplicate values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
...
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE
action_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-04-30'
HAVING MAX(action_date) <= '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY name
```